# vue v-if/v-else does not remove style from buttons

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2, vue.js

I am using vuejs2 for my webapp with bootstrap.

I have two blocks with [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) and v-else, so only one of those renders. I have bootstrap button in each of these blocks. When I press the button from first of div, second div becomes visible and vice versa.

Problem is when I click button of first div, button of second div appears, but still it is focussed, I want to have a normal button, but it is focussed with outline.

Here is simplified code:

```
<div id="app"> 
    <div v-if="switc">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="switc = !switc">
        <span >First</span>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div v-else>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
        <span>Second</span>
      </button>
   </div>
   <br>   <br>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="switc = !switc">
     <span>Switch</span>
   </button>
</div>
```

Here is working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5kdd1wu/), if you press first button, second still shows outline.

Answer (score 3):

I missed this: [key in v-if/else](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key) in docs. Vue tries to render elements as efficiently as possible, often re-using them instead of rendering from scratch. It seems in my case as well it is using the same component and re-rendering it completely.

To fix it I just need to add `key` field in each button, like following:

```
    <div v-if="switc">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="switc = !switc" key="first">
        <span >First</span>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div v-else>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" key="second">
        <span>Second</span>
      </button>
   </div>
```

Updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ovom3jts/).